# python create list within while loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I have defined a function to read lines from a file into a list. I then want to call this function from within a while loop. The list is created correctly on the first loop, but the following loops create an empty list.

How can I get my code to regenerate the list each time? 
(For clarification, this is not the final function, but I have isolated the issue in my code to the generation of the list).

```
def get_random_gene_list(input):
    disease_genes = []
    for line in input:
        disease_genes.append(line.strip())

    return disease_genes

x=0
while x < 5:

    unpack_gene_list = get_random_gene_list(args.i)
    print unpack_gene_list


    x = x + 1
```

Comment: your `get_random_gene_list` function does nothing random.

Comment: Full function is below. As I said in the post, I isolated the issue and did not bother posting the full function. 

def get_random_gene_list(input, subset):

    genes_to_remove = set(random.sample(input, subset))
    genes_to_use = list(set(input) - genes_to_remove)

    return (genes_to_use, genes_to_remove)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that `args.i` is a file object, you're reading the file on the first loop, which puts the file pointer at the end of the file. Do you need to re-read the file every loop? If not, you should call the function once outside the `while` loop and save the resulting list. In fact, you don't even need the function. Also, you should use a `for` loop in this case.

```
unpack_gene_list = list(args.i)

x = 0
for x in range(5):
    print unpack_gene_list
```

Comment: I ended up reading the file outside of the while loop as you suggested. I thought I had tried this, but I must have done something incorrectly.

Do you happen to know why the file wasn't being re-read and save to a list each loop? I don't understand why it stopped at the first loop. Thanks!

Comment: @dana, when you read from a file object, it moves the file pointer forward. You can't re-read the same file object without moving it back.

Comment: ohh, I just looked into that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, unless I misunderstood your question. Problem might lie in your input.

```
k = ['1','1','a','aa']

def get_random_gene_list(input):
    disease_genes = []
    for line in input:
        disease_genes.append(line.strip())
    return disease_genes

x=0
while x < 5:
    unpack_gene_list = get_random_gene_list(k)
    print unpack_gene_list
    x = x + 1
```

Output:

```
['1', '1', 'a', 'aa']
['1', '1', 'a', 'aa']
['1', '1', 'a', 'aa']
['1', '1', 'a', 'aa']
['1', '1', 'a', 'aa']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Yes, I troubleshooted this way as well. I suppose the problem was that my input is reading in from a file. Thanks.